# Ubuntu 17.04 Unity Keyboard Shortcut not working

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 17.04

On Ubuntu 17.04 all the shortcuts are working fine in GNOME, but in Unity they are not working. I cannot open terminal or change language with keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install gnome-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

After installation run this command:

```
gnome-tweak-tool
```

Tap on Keyboard & Mouse --> Turn on Show Extended Input Sources --> Log Out --> Log On.

[image]

Comment: I don't know how it solves OP's problem of non-working keyboard shortcuts to open Terminal or change keyboard layout only in Unity (but not in GNOME). This toggle button just expands the list of available keyboard layouts that can be added (by default GNOME offers a handful of options). But well, OP accepted it,  so it must have done something for them!